# Can security vulnerabilities for testing dependencies threaten my app in production?

Tags: reactjs, security, npm, jestjs, dependency-management

I'm working on a React application. Running `npm audit` revealed the app has quite a few high-level security vulnerabilities.

Most of them are coming from `jest`, a testing framework for React. We'll need to upgrade the package by a few major versions to resolve the vulnerabilities.

I don't know how pressing it is to resolve these vulnerabilities. If `jest` is a testing framework, could it expose my app to threats in production? Can vulnerabilities for testing dependencies threaten to my app in production?

Any advice would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: As long as you are not packaging the jest framework with you app it should be fine.. but if you are then you are in trouble..

Comment: If you are exposing APIs that are specifically for testing, then you have a problem.

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee - what do you mean "packaging the jest framework with your app"? Like including it in the production bundle?

Comment: Correct .. including it in the production bundle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't deploy the testing code/framework in production, you are fine.